# JSON Parse: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token e

Tags: javascript, json, string, parsing

I am trying to parse a JSON string. This is the contents of the string:

```
[[ new Date(2016, 2, 11), 439 ],[ new Date(2016, 2, 10), 1110 ],[ new Date(2016, 2, 9), 9 ],[ new Date(2016, 2, 8), 2 ]]
```

**This is the code**

```
var data = JSON.parse(str);
```

**This is the error**

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token e

How can I prepare this string to be parsed by `JSON.parse()`?

Comment: That's not JSON. What exactly are you trying to do? Where does the string come from? No API that claimed to return JSON would produce that.

Comment: run your "json" [here](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)

Comment: I use Google Graphs. I return this data from PHP. I echoed it in this format so it would be accepted by the calendar. It works when I echo it directly from PHP into JavaScript, but it does not work when I load the data from AJAX and use `JSON.parse()`

Comment: @Z0q — JSON is a data format based on a subset of JavaScript object literal syntax. You can't put any JavaScript expression you like in a JSON text.

Comment: Right, that's because, again, it is not JSON. It *is* valid JavaScript syntax, but that's a *superset* of JSON syntax. You can't embed expressions in JSON, so your dates should be output as strings or timestamps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using:

```
eval( "data = " + str );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace each instance of `new Date(2016, 2, 11)` with a valid JSON data type.

You could express a date with, for example, a string containing a ISO 8601 data or a number representing the seconds since the epoch.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, construct it something like this (http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_syntax.asp)...

```
// Bear in mind that month 2 = March in JavaScript!
var dte1 = new Date(2016, 2, 11);
var dte2 = new Date(2016, 2, 10);
var dte3 = new Date(2016, 2, 9);
var dte4 = new Date(2016, 2, 8);

var str = '[ ';
str += '{ "d": "' + dte1.toJSON() + '", "n": 439 }, ';
str += '{ "d": "' + dte2.toJSON() + '", "n": 1110 }, ';
str += '{ "d": "' + dte3.toJSON() + '", "n": 9 }, ';
str += '{ "d": "' + dte4.toJSON() + '", "n": 2 } ]';

var data = JSON.parse(str);

alert("Date: " + data[0].d);
alert("Amount: " + data[0].n);
```

I've constructed this as an array of objects with properties d and n, to allow you to access the date and the number of each object in the array. You should call these something more meaningful to your needs.